# UITableViewCell has incorrect change on indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I try to use UITableViewCell's accessoryType property to checkmark cell when clicked ,but when cell selected , the checkmark set several time for different cells for example when I select row [0] , row [0] and row [8] and row [17] AccessoryType set to checkmark !

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "npCell", for: indexPath) as! NewPlaylistTableViewCell

    cell.mTitle.text = musics[indexPath.row]["title"] as! String?
    cell.mArtist.text = musics[indexPath.row]["artist"] as! String?

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: you need to track your selected indexPath in a viewController variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single selection, you need to track your selected indexPath in a viewController variable,

```
var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    tableView.reloadData()
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "npCell", for: indexPath) as! NewPlaylistTableViewCell

    cell.mTitle.text = musics[indexPath.row]["title"] as! String?
    cell.mArtist.text = musics[indexPath.row]["artist"] as! String?

    cell.accessoryType = .none
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    if(indexPath == selectedIndexPath) {
       cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }

    return cell
}
```

**Even better (avoiding reload the entire UITableView)**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let previousSelectedIndexPath = self.selectedIndexPath
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        if(previousSelectedIndexPath != nil) {
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [previousSelectedIndexPath!,self.selectedIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
        }else{
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [self.selectedIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

## UPDATE, Allowing multiple selection

For multiple selection you should track selected cells in a `Dictionary` for convenience faster access to selected and unselected indexPaths allowing you use multiple sections because the key value of our Dictionary is a string formed by (IndexPath.section)+(IndexPath.row) which is always unique combination

```
var selectedIndexPaths : [String:Bool] = [:]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let currentIndexPathStr = "\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row)"
    if(self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr] == nil || !self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr]!) {
        self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr] = true
    }else{
        self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr] = false
    }
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "npCell", for: indexPath) as! NewPlaylistTableViewCell

        cell.mTitle.text = musics[indexPath.row]["title"] as! String?
        cell.mArtist.text = musics[indexPath.row]["artist"] as! String?

        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        let currentIndexPathStr = "\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row)"
        if(self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr] == nil || !self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr]!)  {
           cell.accessoryType = .none
        }

        return cell
    }
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: but I need multi select option ( for selecting musics from tableView to create playlist ) , this code use for one select option

Comment: your table have one or multiple sections @user3722311 ?

Comment: one section ( numberOfSections return 1 )

Comment: but update your code ( cell.accessoryType = .none
        cell.selectionStyle = .checkmark ) to ( cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        cell.selectionStyle = . none )